# how to set bgimg in 100% textbox?

Tags: css

I'm building a mobile webapp and looking for a solution for the following:

```
[searchbox [img]]
```

where searchbox should be of width 100%. and img inside the inputbox.

Tried three solutions of which none works well enough:

First, wrap with div for 'false' border+borderless inputbox.

```
[div[textbox][img]]
```

Problem looks ok but on focus of textbox the textbox gets and ugly border anyway.

--

Second, position image relative (left:-40px)

```
[textbox][img]
```

Problem Can't set textbox width to 100%, img wraps to next row, no respect to -40px;

--

Third,
Background-image in textbox, right-align

Problem: Image isn't clickable.

Hints here? Perhaps bg-img + relative img (0x0px) to catch the click, but it itches.

Comment: could you post your three options in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution should work fine, just add `input:focus {outline:none}` to your css:

http://jsfiddle.net/L9gyp/2/

Comment: thanks for your effort, however, on an android device, the outline:none seem to have no effect upon focus of textbox.